# Can Asta create an Anti Magic Black Divider sword using the Demon Destroyer Sword instead of the Demon Slayer Sword?

Tags: black-clover

In episode #119 Asta used his Demon Slayer sword to create the Anti-Magic Demon Slayer Sword Black Divider. Can Asta create an Anti Magic Black Divider sword using the Demon Destroyer Sword instead of the Demon Slayer Sword?

Answer (score -1):

I dont think so because if it were possible it would b too op plus it would have been listed in the manga already, but that is still a possibility.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.